# Como substituir eval() por outra expressão

Tags: javascript

Lendo alguns comentários e principalmente os comentários do colega TobyMosque, procuro hoje evitar o uso do eval(). Bem, agora vem o seguinte. Em expressões simples, como eu o substituo? Veja abaixo uma declaração de variável que eu peguei aqui no sistema em que eu trabalho e veja se minha abordagem é correta? Devido a um problema que tivemos aqui hoje, não estou conseguindo testar e no jsfiddle não dá, pois na página tem muita chamada asp e é extremamente grande, pois há dependência de outras páginas.

```
function prorrogaVencimento(pLinha) {
        var intI = pLinha;
        var v_num_seq_cobranca = eval('form01.num_seq_cobranca_' + intI + '.value');
        var v_nom_tipo_ciclo = eval('form01.nom_tipo_ciclo_' + intI + '.value');

        var v_txt_num_linha_digitavel = eval('form01.num_linha_digitavel_' + intI + '.value');
        var v_num_seq_fatura_ts = eval('form01.num_seq_fatura_ts_' + intI + '.value');
        var v_ind_tipo_cobranca = eval('form01.ind_tipo_cobranca_' + intI + '.value');
        var v_mes_ano_ref = eval('form01.mes_ano_ref_' + intI + '.value');
        var v_ind_situacao = eval('form01.ind_situacao_' + intI + '.value');
        if ((v_ind_tipo_cobranca == '5' || v_ind_tipo_cobranca == '6') & v_ind_situacao == 'Vencidas' {
            alert('Ação não permitida para o tipo da cobrança.');
            return;
        }
```

Fiz assim, mas acho que tá ruim:

```
var v_num_seq_cobranca = eval('form01.num_seq_cobranca_' + intI + '.value');
```

para isso:

```
var v_num_seq_cobranca = form01.num_seq_cobranca_[intI].value;
```

Tem essa outra abordagem também:

```
var v_num_seq_cobranca = window['form01.num_seq_cobranca_' + intI].value;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

De fato essa alteração não produzirá o resultado esperado. Entretanto, em JavaScript toda propriedade pode ser acessada por meio dos colchetes. De modo que isso:

```
foo.bar
```

É o mesmo que isso:

```
foo["bar"]
```

E a propósito, sendo `window` o objeto global, o mesmo acesso pode ser feito também dessa forma (mas só caso `foo` seja uma variável global):

```
window["foo"]["bar"]
```

Sendo assim, uma forma de acessar uma propriedade cujo nome só se conhece em tempo de execução é "montando" a string e usando os colchetes para acessar a propriedade com o nome correspondente:

```
var v_num_seq_cobranca = form01['num_seq_cobranca_' + intI].value;
```

Note que, como tanto `form01` quanto `value` são estáticos, pode-se acessá-los normalmente (pelo nome, e pelo ponto), sem precisar criar uma string explícita para isso.

### Adendo

Sua primeira tentativa:

```
var v_num_seq_cobranca = form01.num_seq_cobranca_[intI].value;
```

Não produz o resultado esperado pois ela está acessando uma propriedade chamada `num_seq_cobranca_` e dentro dela tentando acessar uma cujo nome é o valor de `intI`:

```
var intI = 10;
var v_num_seq_cobranca = form01["num_seq_cobranca_"][intI]["value"]
```

Já sua segunda tentativa:

```
var v_num_seq_cobranca = window['form01.num_seq_cobranca_' + intI].value;
```

Está tentando acessar uma variável chamada `form01.num_seq_cobranca_10` (sim, propriedades e variáveis globais podem conter caracteres especiais! Mas só se declaradas/acessadas dessa forma...), e não duas propriedades uma dentro da outra.

```
var v_num_seq_cobranca = window['form01.num_seq_cobranca_10']['value'];
```

Comment: Valeu, eu optei pela sua primeira abridagem que é a mesma do bfavaretto.

Comment: Na realidade essa abordagem é a "única" correta (no sentido de "mínima"). O resto da resposta está só exemplificando os conceitos, e mostrando qual seria o resultado das suas outras tentativas.

Answer (score 4):

Eu faria assim:

```
var v_num_seq_cobranca = form01['num_seq_cobranca_' + intI].value;
```